# MVC2 Routing + Ajax ==?

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

Im touching up an mvc2 application thats nearly complete, I have some ajax requests that end up looking alot like

www.host.com/site/controller/action?UserName=asdf&UserPassword=asdfasdf&Email=asd%40df.com&PhoneNumber=541-345-5433&CompanyName="sdf"

So my question is how (if possible) can I mask the ajax url on the redirect to simply be.. /controller/action, Im getting the feeling I broke pattern with my ajax and am stuck with nasty URLS.

any mvc2 gurus out there willing to clarify?

Comment: Can you post the code where you register your routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using jquery try this:

> ```
> $.ajax({
>     url: '/controller/action';,
>     data: {
>         UserName: 'asdf',
>         UserPassword: 'asdfasdf',
>         Email: 'asd%40df.com',
>         PhoneNumber: '541-345-5433',
>         CompanyName: 'sdf'
>     },
>     success: function(req, status, error) {
>         updateSucceeded();
>     },
>     error: function(req, status, error) {
>         updateFailed(error);
>     }
> });
> ```

Be happy and enjoy life.

Comment: My ajax request jquery side is working for me, its when I get the call back and redirect to get the page I want on success, it sends the parameters in the URL on the redirect. So Im looking for a way to route it so the url hides the parameters entirely.

Comment: @Gnostus - Sorry I've lost you - can you please clarify

Comment: :D sorry its early still. I click a button that grabs some information and sends a request to the server that hands me back a url to redirect to. That url has the parameters in it that I want to be hidden.

Comment: @Gnostus - If I understand you correctly the userName , userPassword etc arrive from the server and where not known on the client. P.S for me the time now is 20:00 ;-)

Comment: @Gnostos - Can't you send the data back to the client using JSON?

Comment: maybe im not looking at this correctly...

the situation is user click a row that has the user key, I sling it up with ajax to the server and get a redirect to the user edit page with the user model as parameters, but on redirect it displays all the parameters in the final url.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, I would say never send a password through a URL variable. They're totally sniffable even if you're using HTTPS.

Comment: yea, I had a painful time getting mvc2 post's working at all in the beginning, and that is included in my checklist for hardening :D thanks for the heads up though.